# Eclipse how to change bean.text to bean.gettext()

Tags: eclipse, groovy

i have a bunch of variables in my java bean which i am using in another groovy class like

```
def abc = bean.variable1
def abcd = bean.variable2
```

is there any shortcut in eclipse to replace all these like

```
def abc = bean.getVariable1()
def abcd = bean.getVariable2()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can generate getters and setter by opening the context menu (i.e. right click) in the source code window of the desired class. Then select the Source submenu; from that menu selecting Generate Getters and Setters... will cause a wizard window will appear.

Source -> Generate Getters and Setters...

Select the variables you wish to create getters and setters for and click OK.

Or you can use Alt+Shift+R to rename every occurrence of a variable inside of one document.

Answer (score 1):

bean.variable1 and bean.variable2 infers to me that you're using `public` or at least `default` visibility for your variables.

I cannout conclude from your question if you are programming an object, but if you do, you *should always set the visibility to private* and then use getter- and setter-methods as @Yannick Huber already mentioned. 
To ease it up you can select all you variables, then rightclick > Source > Generate Getters and Setters and everything will be done for you automatically, also generating JavaDoc comments if you want.

If you do so, you should access those variables from outsie the class only by using setVariable1(...) and getVariable1();